# change the source of observable at runtime (rxjs)

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

i need to change the source of an observable with a swith
.

```
this.su = this.appService._sub1.subscribe(data => {
  this.items.push(data);
});

//appService
  setSub(name) {
    if (name == 'A') {
      console.log('B');
      this._sub1 = this.sub2;
    } else if (name == 'B') {
      console.log('B');
      this._sub1 = this.sub3;
    }
    console.log(this._sub1);
  }
```

however, the source of the first observable keeps sending data, how can I do it?

Stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evczcx?file=src/app/app.service.ts

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, I think you will want to use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).  You don't really want to switch the subscription, but rather the source.

It's cleaner if you design your service to expose observables, then have your components subscribe to them (*ideally with AsyncPipe*).

As a sample, something like this should work:

```js
export class AppService {
  private source$ = new BehaviorSubject<SourceType>('frutas');
  private frutas = ['pera', 'manzana', 'platano', 'fresa'];
  private electronicos = ['celular', 'pc', 'cable'];

  private frutas$ = interval(2000).pipe(
    map(n => n % 4), 
    map(i => this.frutas[i])
  );

  private electronicos$ = interval(2000).pipe(
    map(n => n % 3), 
    map(i => this.electronicos[i])
  );

  data$ = this.source$.pipe(
    switchMap(source => source === 'frutas' ? this.frutas$ : this.electronicos$)
  );

  setSource(name: SourceType) {
    this.source$.next(name);
  }
}
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-68600449?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping a reference to a subscription does nothing to the subscription itself. You need to unsubscribe. Also keep in mind, that `interval` produces a "hot" observable. Meaning it will push data to the stream wether someone has subscribed or not.

In real life, you would probably use something like `httpClient.get()` which is not "hot" (runs only when subscribed to, and completes once it's done). So it's not an issue usually, but with `interval`, you will end up with memory leaks and performance hits unless you manually stop the scheduler from running.

```
this._sub1.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: hello friend i understand your point, it is just an example but i need to do something like what i indicate, change the reference of the observable at runtime